# Javascript mouse coordinates behaving differently in Firefox and Chrome when clicking and dragging outside of a box

Tags: javascript, mousemove

On https://javascript.info/mouse-events-basics#coordinates-clientx-y-pagex-y there is a sample that is outputting the X and Y position of the mouse when you move it within a box.

In Firefox (Version 70.0) if I click on the box and drag horizontally outside the right edge, then the X/Y position values increase past the width of the box.

However, in Chrome (Version 77.0.3865.120) the X/Y position values never go past the box width (170 or so).

Why is that? 
How can I make Chrome behave like Firefox for this case?

Thanks in advance.

Tom

Comment: You'd probably have to add a document-level event listener, and translate the window coordinates of the events received that way to the element's coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Firefox. If you want to achieve the same on other browsers (or on Firefox without relying on a bug) you will need to:

1. capture element clientX and clientY
2. on element click, add document-level mousemove listener, get clientX and clientY from there, subtract your element's clientX and clientY, do something with them
3. on document-level mouseup, remove mousemove listener

something like this

```
const element = document.getElementById('someId')
const clientRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
const elementX = clientRect.left;
const elementY = clientRect.top;

element.addEventListener('mousedown', function moveListener() {
  function documentMoveListener(e) {
    console.log(e.clientX - elementX, e.clientY - elementY)
  }

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', documentMoveListener)
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function mouseUpListener() {
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpListener)
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', documentMoveListener)
  })
})
```